# ActiveMQ on TCP giving unknown data type: 47

Tags: java, sockets, tcp, activemq-classic

I want to read values coming on a TCP port and push them in the Queue. So that when the consumer is available, they can be consumed from the other end.

I am trying to use ActiveMQ for the same. I have kept the default activemq.xml:

```
    <transportConnectors>
        <!-- DOS protection, limit concurrent connections to 1000 and frame size to 100MB -->
        <transportConnector name="openwire" uri="tcp://0.0.0.0:61616?maximumConnections=1000&amp;wireFormat.maxFrameSize=104857600"/>
    </transportConnectors>
```

How do I push the data from the TCP port to a Queue using ActiveMQ?

When I run the code to connect on a TCP socket I get:

```
jvm 1    |  WARN | Transport Connection to: tcp://127.0.0.1:50473 failed: java.i
o.IOException: Unknown data type: 47
```

The piece of code that I ran is as below:

```
public static void main(String argv[]) throws Exception
    {
              try
              {
                 Socket client = new Socket("localhost", 61616);
                 OutputStream outToServer = client.getOutputStream();
                 DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(outToServer);
                 DateFormat dateFormat = new SimpleDateFormat("dd/MM/yyyy");
                 Date todayDate = new Date();
                 out.writeUTF(dateFormat.format(todayDate)+"  Content gets received in server"+"\n");

                 client.close();
              }catch(IOException e)
              {
                 e.printStackTrace();
              }
    }
```

Answer (score 1):

You are trying to write raw data to a socket that is expecting to receive binary data using the OpenWire protocol that is the default in ActiveMQ.  You need to use a real client, such as the ActiveMQ native java client, or one in C++, .NET.

You could use the STOMP transport connector to provide a mechanism to write raw text based commands but you'd still need to adhere the semantics of the STOMP protocol there.

I suggest you do some more reading on how JMS Brokers in general work.

Comment: Sure I will..Thanks for the response. My concern here is that I will be connecting the devices which will be sending me the string data on the TCP over a particular port. e.g. Device to host:<’C’><0x02><data 1><data 2>...So I guess in this the data will be of the form of text or string and would not adhere to Openwire protocol..Just like we have a socket code that reads from a port, cant activemq do the same job?

Comment: Nope, how would a JMS broker have any idea what to do with some random data shoved into a socket?

Comment: Good Point.. I thought of it and I was planning to use something like Camel or servicemix which could pick the data from the socket at a particular port to route it to a JMS or to some other component. But again, I get stuck with the same issue as above as it internally involves ActiveMQ

Comment: You would need to take the data from the point you read it off the socket and route it to the ActiveMQ component in Camel.

Comment: Yeah.. I went through nabble and realised that the data routing should happen through CAMEL.. but how would CAMEL pick the data from the socket..I am stuck there ..

Comment: That's an altogether unrelated question to the original, which I believe should now be marked as answered